# Natural number fomula

Tags: real-numbers, education

There is natural number formula

$ a=a_na_{n-1}....a_0a_1$

For example: how to choose n for 1001, ?

It means i need to use 3 places value or how to do that ?

$1001=a_0a_1a_2a_3 $

n=3 ?

Comment: I’m not quite sure what this means. I’m guessing this is translated, perhaps get someone to double check what you wrote to ensure it makes sense?

Comment: Romain S, ok, try to explain again. I have this formula for natural number, $a$ in this formula means number - natural number. Maybe i don't wrote it correct but i want use this formula for 1001 number and want to understand how to pick right $n$ for this.

Comment: Do you mean "how many digits does $a$ have"?

Comment: fleablood. Nice answer, thanks for effort. It's quite near. Maybe i need read USA mathbook for meet the terms and ideas. Maybe russian math is another world haha.
I only want to undersand how to pick right $n$ for example : for 1001

Comment: flearblood. For example : we choose n=1 for 10. because 10 is have 2 digits.
$a_0=0, a_1=1$

Comment: So, in general, however many digits the number has, choose $n$ to be one less than that. So, is the question, "how do you tell how many digits a number has"?

Comment: Are you still here, Alexey?

Answer (score 0):

I had to read three or four times to get what you mean. but I *finally* figured out that you meant: how do we know how many digits a number has.  And if the one's digit counts as the $0$th term what is the index of the final term.

If $100000...... 000 = 10^k \le a \le 99999......9 = 10^{k+1} -1< 10^{k+1}$ then $a$ has $k+1$ digits and the index of the final term is $k$.

$\log_{10} (10^k) \le \log_{10} a  < \log_{10} 10^{k+1}$ so

$k \le \log_{10} a < k+1$.

The the index of the final term is $k =\lfloor \log_{10} a\rfloor$, that is the largest integer equal to or less than $\log_{10} a$.

But the actual number of digits is $k+1$.